# `doParallel` vs `future` while using `Seurat` package

Tags: r, hpc, doparallel, seurat, r-future

Here is the story.

From Seurat [vignette](https://satijalab.org/seurat/archive/v3.0/future_vignette.html), `FindMarkers()` can be accelerated by utilizing `future` package, `future::plan("multiprocess", workers = 4)`

However, I am running a simulation that I need to use `FindAllMarkers()` inside a `doParallel::foreach()` loop after `doParallel::registerDoParallel(numCores=10)`.

1. What's the parallelization that happened behind the scene?
2. How to leverage the most power of HPC under this setup?
3. How many CPUs should I allocate for this job to maximize the parallelization?

Any idea is welcome.

Below is a minimum example. `pbmc.rds` is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TIOQGp-rs__P7lRmnH7c9Q_a_ypY6Utq/view?usp=sharing).

```
library(Seurat)

# Enable parallelization for `FindAllMarkers()`
library(future)
plan("multiprocess", workers = 4)


# Enable parallelization for `foreach()` loop
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cores = 10)

pbmc <- readRDS("pbmc.rds")

rst <- foreach(i = 1:10/10, .combine = "cbind") %doPar% {
  
  pbmc <- FindClusters(pbmc, resolution = i)
  
  # should put future command here instead?
  # plan("multiprocess", workers = 4)
  
  DEgenes <- FindAllMarkers(pbmc)
  
  write.csv(DEgenes, paste0("DEgenes_resolution_", i, "csv"))
  
  pbmc$seurat_clusters
}
```